# Why does powershell freeze for a bit when running my python scripts

Tags: python, powershell, windows-7

Sometime I look back at my terminal when there is a python script running and the console output has frozen, then I right-click on the terminal and the console output (printing to screen) beings again.

Its a bit disconcerting because sometimes I think my script has broken.

Do others also experience this?  Anybody know a fix?

Thanks in advance for any responses

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's intermittent with all other factors being unchanged, it sounds like you've inadvertently selected some text in the PowerShell console and it's halted updating output so that you can do something with it.

Next time, be careful to look to see if you have something selected before clicking.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @alroc's suggestion; i.e. the cause could be accidentally clicking on the console.

A solution to prevent this is to right click on the powershell console window's title bar, select properties, uncheck Quick Edit Mode, then click OK.  This disables some features (i.e. copy by select & enter, paste by right click), but means if you accidentally click on the screen it does no harm.

Another solution's to simply press escape (or right click in the script's window) if the script's taking a while - generally that'll do no harm (i.e. it won't terminate your script), but it will exit the edit session, allowing the script to resume if it had been paused due to edit mode.

To play with these, run the below script, then click on the screen whilst it's running (this script just outputs a bunch of numbers).

```
1..99999999
```

To terminate the script completely, press ctrl+c.